# UIDataDetectorTypeAll and popup in app (or at least ask before switching)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Hey guys, I've recently implemented a UITextView into my app, and activated UIDataDetectorTypeAll. Everything works perfect, except when users click on the link, phone number, etc. it automatically kicks them out of my app and into the website, etc. Is there any way to have the website appear in my own app in a custom view, or at least have a popup that asks the user if they want to be taken to the website, call, etc?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIWebView and message it to load the URL. Wait, that's no help, sounds like you need to intercept the link so you can know the URL. The UITextView may be calling UIApplication's openURL function. This is ugly, but what if you replaced that openURL with your own using categories or subclassed UIApplication and added your own openURL function to override the one at the UIApplication level. Once there, you have a chance to intercept the call and direct it to your own UIWebView or at least pop up a UIAlertView.